# One word for the person who is not serious about his or her career in life?

Tags: single-word-requests

As I am not serious about my career. I don't know what I want to do in life. And if I plan to start work, laziness pulls my feet back. So, what will be the one word for me.

Comment: Do you mean to say you are undecided on a carrier or you have a carrier and are not enthusiastic about it? you should  ad some details and  an example sentence  to your question to avoid it being closed or put on hold.

Comment: Perhaps: ***lackadaisical***

Comment: dilettante or dabbler